# How to have instance variables persist within included Ruby modules

Tags: ruby, variables, module, persistence

I have a module that i am including in a few classes. Each class calculates different percentages for the modules methods.

Having calculations that are shared i thought i would abstract them into a singular module to include the shared methods. But the instance variables from the classes are not persisting into the modules methods.

So just to demonstrate the principle:

```
module Models::CharteredAccountancyMethods
  def calculated_npat_or_calculated_revenue
    [calculated_npat, calculated_revenue].max
  end

....
....

  def calculated_npat
    return 0 if @npat_percentage.to_f.zero?
    return scorecard.npat.to_f * @npat_percentage.to_f
  end

  def calculated_revenue
    return 0 if @revenue_percentage.to_f.zero? 
    return scorecard.general.revenue.to_f * @revenue_percentage.to_f
  end
end
```

This module is included in 3 classes. all of which need the `calculated_npat_or_calculated_revenue` method.

An example of a class:

```
class CharteredAccountancyGenericEnterpriseDevelopment < GenericEnterpriseDevelopment
  include Models::CharteredAccountancyMethods
  @npat_percentage = 0.03
  @revenue_percentage = 0.00375
  ....
  ....
end
```

The methods defined within the module work fine it picks up things like the `scorecard` object from the `EnterpriseDevelopment` class, which is then given it to it's child object the `GenericEnterpriseDevelopment` class through inheritance, and works fine.

Only if i call the `calculated_npat` method within the module the `@npat_percentage` will return 0. So it seems as if the `@npat_percentage` that is defined within the class is not persisting to the module methods that are included. Why is this? especially when just plain old inherited methods work.

I mean i could i suppose make them global variables or define a method that just returns a percentage. i thought it was really odd? and what is the best practice to do in such a situation. i dont want to have confusing methods or any global variables for that matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `include` the module's methods run on your class's *instances*. When you declared `@npat_percentage` you declared it in your class's static context, where it is not visible to the instances.

You should use `extend` instead, see [here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/):

```
class CharteredAccountancyGenericEnterpriseDevelopment < GenericEnterpriseDevelopment
  extend Models::CharteredAccountancyMethods
  @npat_percentage = 0.03
  @revenue_percentage = 0.00375
  ....
  ....
end
```

Or alternatively, set the variables inside the `def initialize` method:

```
class CharteredAccountancyGenericEnterpriseDevelopment < GenericEnterpriseDevelopment
  include Models::CharteredAccountancyMethods

  def initialize
    @npat_percentage = 0.03
    @revenue_percentage = 0.00375
  end
  ....
  ....
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much Uri for the link its helped me understand the difference between extend and include.